# SQLMembershipProvider - source code

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, sqlmembershipprovider

Where can I find the source code for SQLMembershipProvider (.NET2.0)? 
Is it available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code has been released. [See ScottGu's blog for further details](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Steven, I saw that page before (that is the first result from google) but somehow the link did not work on Chrome I opened it again with Firefox and it was fine; Here is the link http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi

Answer (score 2):

The source code can be find [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/b/3/ab3c284b-dc9a-473d-b7e3-33bacfcc8e98/ProviderToolkitSamples.msi) It is .msi installer.

It will install the code samples in c:\Program Files\ASP.NET Provider Toolkit SQL Samples\

Answer (score 1):

i guess it's not freely available. but as long as it's just for educational purposes and you don't want to make money out of it, microsoft will not sue you if you use reflector to have a look at it ;)