# Changing SqlMembershipProvider to use MD5, Joomla-style passwords

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, md5, joomla1.7

I'm trying to migrate users from a Joomla database to a custom one using the default asp.net tables and providers. Theoretically I can change the hash type from the default (SHA) to MD5 by changing web.config, however, when logging in it reports an invalid password (or username, but I doubt it's that). Examining the aspnet_Membership table and the Joomla_users table I can see both have the same password and salt values per user (Joomla 1.7 actually stores it as password:salt but that's easy to split into two fields). Both appear to be in base64 format, and adding a user through the ASP default log in control results in a similar pair of fields for the new user (though the salt is randomized I think, so I can't compare with the same known password).

Here's an extract from my web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey validation="MD5"/>
  ...
<membership hashAlgorithmType="MD5">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="UserAuth"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
</system.web>
```

One thing I'm not sure on is whether it's md5, Md5, or MD5 (I've seen both the latter in code samples while Googling). However, I can write nonsense instead and the application doesn't appear to bat an eyelid.

I don't particularly wish to write a custom membership provider unless there is no other way.

Here's some PHP that compares the Joomla hashed password with one supplied as a parameter to this function:

```
                $user_id = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
                $db_password = mysql_result($result, 0, 'password');
                $joomla = &New JConfig;
                list($md5pass, $saltpass) = split(":", $db_password);
                $md5_password = md5($user_password.$saltpass);
                if (strcmp($md5_password, $suppliedpass) == 0)
                {
                    return $user_id;
                }
```

Either the ASP version is ignoring my md5 request, or somehow it's storing it in some other way, or I'm not telling it to use md5 correctly, or...? I don't want to tell 4000 users to reset their passwords, though I'm aware md5 is not recommended these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I worked it out. In Joomla, from the PHP code, the md5 is applied to pass+salt. In SqlMembershipProvider.cs it's applied to salt+pass.

The SqlMembershipProvider.cs was found via [SQLMembershipProvider - source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298556/sqlmembershipprovider-source-code) - maybe not the true source but I see no reason why it should be different from the true source in that particular aspect.